# Docker-compose: can I map user ids per container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For a local dev setup under Linux, I run a bunch of third-party containers using docker-compose, and mount a volume for them. The containers create some files on that volume, which is a local directory on my disk.

If I run the containers as root, the files they create belong to root.Running other tools that look at them via `sudo` does not feel good.

Internally the containers run their software as non-root users. *But the user IDs of these non-root users vary.* Say, in one container it's 999, in another, 1000, in yet another, 1001.

Can I map the in-container user id to the "outer" user id of my choice, *separately for each container?* My goal is to have all containers look like they run under the same "outer" user id (my interactive user id). That is, I'd like every container to act as if it runs under id=1000, and access the filesystem under this same uid.

So far I found DOcker documentation that shows how to shift user ids and thus shift in-container root  to a non-root user id, but if only applies to all containers equally.